# T-SQL Case Statement confusion

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a legacy query that I am cleaning up and I am getting confused with this case statement so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN bitdelivered = 1 THEN
    '' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101)
    + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    + '&#254;' + '
' -- this is a carriage return, do not remove it
  WHEN bitdelivered = 0 AND deliv.dtmdeliverydate < Getdate() THEN
    '' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101)
    + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    + '&#168;' + '
'
  ELSE
    '' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101)
    + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
    + '&#168;' + '
'
END
```

Like I said it is very dirty, however when I run the entire query, if I get a 0 for bitdelivered, the casestatement works as it should, however if I get a 1 returned, then I return a null instead of the else block.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**  I have edited the code as shown below for easier readability and I still get null...

```
select
CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101) +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
CASE 
    WHEN bitdelivered = 1 THEN '&#254;'
    ELSE '&#168;'
END + '
'
```

**EDIT x 2** Here is the entire (very nasty I know) sql query, I did not write this I am just trying to clean it up...

```
SELECT dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid,
       tblcontracting.strdescription                             AS
       strcontracting,
       dbo.viewawardnumbers.strcontractnumber                    AS
       strawardnumber,
       Ltrim(Rtrim(dbo.viewawardnumbers.strtonumber))            AS strtonumber,
       dbo.tblrequirements.strdescription,
       dbo.tblezquerycontractvalue.curtotalvalue,
       dbo.tblcodescontractvehicles.strdescription               AS
       strcontractvehicle,
       tblcustomer.stracronym                                    AS strcustomer,
       dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription            AS strstatus,
       Substring(dbo.tblrequirements.strnotes, 0, 512)           AS strnotes,
       Coalesce (dbo.tblrequirements.guidfromid,
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       )                                                         AS guidfromid,
       Coalesce (dbo.viewteammembers.guidpersonid,
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')                   AS guidpersonid
       ,
       dbo.viewcurrentoptions.dtmstart,
       dbo.viewcurrentoptions.dtmend,
       Dateadd(d, -60, dbo.viewcurrentoptions.dtmend)            AS
       dtm1stnoticedue,
       Dateadd(d, -30, dbo.viewcurrentoptions.dtmend)            AS
       dtm2ndnoticedue,
       dbo.tblcontractdates.dtmcontractstart,
       dbo.tblcontractdates.dtmcontractend,
       Isnull(dbo.viewteammembers.strshortname, ' Not Assigned') AS strshortname
       ,
       dbo.tblezqueryfunding.curtotalfunded,
       CASE
         WHEN ( dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                'Pre-Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Source Selection'
              ) THEN 'P'
         WHEN ( Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'IT'
                AND Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'OPS'
              ) THEN
         'S'
         ELSE 'C'
       END                                                       AS strproctype,
       dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode,
       dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strdescription               AS strprocdesc,
       deliveries.dtmdeliverydate,
       deliveries.bitdelivered,
       CASE
         WHEN ( dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                'Pre-Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Source Selection'
              ) THEN 'Initial Start Date'
         WHEN ( Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'IT'
                AND Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'OPS'
              ) THEN
         'POP'
         ELSE 'Delivery Date'
       END                                                       AS
       colpopdelivdt,
       CASE
         WHEN ( dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                'Pre-Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Solicitation'
                 OR dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strdescription =
                    'Source Selection'
              ) THEN 'Req Award Date'
         WHEN ( Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'IT'
                AND Coalesce (dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode, '') <> 'OPS'
              ) THEN
         'Option Notice'
         ELSE 'Delivered'
       END                                                       AS
       coloptnotdeliv,
       tblpresolicitations.dtmcontacted,
       tblpresolicitations.dtmrequiredby,
       tblpresolicitations.dtmawardnotice,
       strjobid,
       bitprimary
FROM   dbo.tblrequirements
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses
         ON dbo.tblcodesrequirementstatuses.strcode =
            dbo.tblrequirements.strstatusid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblezquerycontractvalue
         ON dbo.tblezquerycontractvalue.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.viewawardnumbers
         ON dbo.viewawardnumbers.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblezqueryfunding
         ON dbo.tblezqueryfunding.strawardnumber =
            dbo.viewawardnumbers.strawardnumber
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.viewcurrentoptions
         ON dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.viewcurrentoptions.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.viewteammembers
         ON dbo.viewteammembers.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblcontracts
         ON dbo.tblcontracts.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblcontractdates
         ON dbo.tblcontractdates.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblcodescontractvehicles
         ON dbo.tblcodescontractvehicles.strcode = dbo.tblcontracts.strvehicleid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblorganizations AS tblcontracting
         ON dbo.tblrequirements.guidfromid = tblcontracting.guidorgid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblorganizations AS tblcustomer
         ON dbo.tblrequirements.guidtoid = tblcustomer.guidorgid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblpresolicitations
         ON dbo.tblpresolicitations.guidrequirementid =
            dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes
         ON dbo.tblcodesprocurementtypes.strcode =
            dbo.tblpresolicitations.strprocurementtypeid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT guidrequirementid,
                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (
(select
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101), '(no date)') +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
CASE 
    WHEN bitdelivered = 1 THEN '&#254;'
    ELSE '&#168;'
END + '
'



                                       /*(SELECT CASE
                                                 WHEN bitdelivered = 1
                                               THEN
                                                 ''
                                                 +
                                                 CONVERT(CHAR(10),
       deliv.dtmdeliverydate,
       101) +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
+ '&#254;' + '

'
WHEN bitdelivered = 0
AND deliv.dtmdeliverydate < Getdate() THEN
'' +
CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101) +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
+ '&#168;' + '

'
ELSE 
'' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101) +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
+ '&#168;' + '

'
END*/
FROM   tblclins clins
INNER JOIN tblcommodities commod
ON commod.guidclinid = clins.guidclinid
INNER JOIN tbldeliveries deliv
ON deliv.guidcommodityid = commod.guidcommodityid
WHERE  clins.guidrequirementid = req.guidrequirementid
AND deliv.bitdelivered = 0
ORDER  BY guidrequirementid,
deliv.dtmdeliverydate
FOR XML PATH('')), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&amp;', '&') AS dtmdeliverydate
,
Stuff ((SELECT '|' + CAST(bitdelivered AS CHAR(1))
FROM   tblclins clins
INNER JOIN tblcommodities commod
ON commod.guidclinid = clins.guidclinid
INNER JOIN tbldeliveries deliv
ON deliv.guidcommodityid = commod.guidcommodityid
WHERE  clins.guidrequirementid = req.guidrequirementid
ORDER  BY guidrequirementid
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')                          AS bitdelivered
FROM   tblrequirements req
GROUP  BY guidrequirementid) deliveries
  ON deliveries.guidrequirementid = dbo.tblrequirements.guidrequirementid
```

Comment: God bless you, that's ugly =/

Comment: Is it possible that `deliv.dtmdeliverydate` is NULL?  I would hope not since your `bitdelivered` is 1 in that case.

Comment: @StevieG Don't get rid of the carriage returns in your edit. They are clearly there for formatting.

Comment: @EvanGWatkins - As per an answer here before your edit; if any part of the concatenation yields NULL, the whole returns NULL.  This leads me to suspect that `deliv.dtmdeliverydate` is NULL.  Test this by including it as a stand alone field in your results.

Comment: when I go through an look as the specific deliveries table the dtmdeliverydate is not null for any of these

Comment: @EvanGWatkins hmm maybe you're looking at it wrong. For giggles try  `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` before you run your query

Comment: @EvanGWatkins when you say "no go" does that mean you're still getting Nulls?

Comment: @ConradFrix yes sorry about that, still getting nulls, but when I pull out the join that pulls the data from the deliveries table I get delivery dates

Comment: @EvanGWatkins I think we're missing something perhaps you should post the full SQL

Comment: @ConradFrix I have posted the entire query, it is very ugly and nasty...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6395/discussion-between-conrad-frix-and-evangwatkins)

Comment: @ConradFrix I am in the chat, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause of the CASE Statement is this

```
WHEN bitdelivered = 1
```

So it will never go into the ELSE Statement which you seem to think it should by this statement "however if I get a 1 returned, then I return a null instead of the else block"

If you're getting nulls from this case statement its because `deliv.dtmdeliverydate` is `NULL` and [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) is set to `ON`

You should fix this using `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`. You could change the setting `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` to OFF, but I don't recommend this as this setting surprises people.

However as we figured out during [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6395) the WHERE Clause on the derived table

`WHERE clins.guidrequirementid = req.guidrequirementid AND deliv.bitdelivered = 0` means that

`CASE WHEN bitdelivered = 1`

will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that `deliv.dtmdeliverydate` is `NULL` in that case.

If it is, then `CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101)` will yield `NULL` and concatenating that to a string will yield `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it for one. I may have missed a few carriage returns

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(10), deliv.dtmdeliverydate, 101), '(no date)') +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
CASE 
    WHEN bitdelivered = 1 THEN '&#254;'
    ELSE '&#168;'
END + '
'
```

Comment: I have now used your simplification however it is still returning null not 'no date'

Comment: @EvanGWatkins: in that case, the problem isn't in the code you gave us.

Answer (score 0):

if deliv.dtmdeliverydate is null when your bitdelivered is 1, then the resulting value will be null..